# Angular 8 Intercept and modify Http Error Response

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, observable, interceptor

I need to intercept and modify an HttpResponse which is instance of HttpErrorResponse i.e status: 500, with the status 200 and fill in its body so I can handle it in my http.post's Observable's subscription as a success http call.

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow, what have you tried so far? any code to show ..?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to modify the HttpErrorResponse with the following interceptor:

```
export class CustomErrorHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((httpErrorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {

        // Customize as you wish:
        const newHttpErrorResponse = new HttpErrorResponse( {
          error: httpErrorResponse.error,
          headers: httpErrorResponse.headers,
          status: httpErrorResponse.status,
          statusText: httpErrorResponse.statusText,
          url: httpErrorResponse.url
        });

        return Observable.throw(newHttpErrorResponse);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `map` operator and `catchError` from rxjs for handle error. Here the code:

```js
const withoutError = this.http
      .get("https://httpstat.us/500")
      .pipe(
          catchError((error) => {
          // here you can modify your error
          return of(error)
       })
      )
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log("Run, because error has modified", res.status);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log('Never run ...')
      });
```

`https://httpstat.us/500` always response with 500 status code.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j8ywx3) you can see how it is working.